# Python updating lists error! List will not update inside while loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, while-loop, scope

```
grid_height = 4
grid_width = 5
cell = [0, 1]
OFFSETS = (1, 0)

col = []

while (cell[0] < grid_height) and (cell[1] < grid_width):
    print cell
    col.append(cell)
    cell[0] += OFFSETS[0]
    cell[1] += OFFSETS[1]

print col
```

So for this Python code, I try to get update the "cell" list and store every single new value to the list "col". However, if you run this code in Python, the value of the "cell" that is printing out is exactly the value I want to have, but when I print out "col", it just keeps repeating the value of the last, unwanted, out-of-range value of "cell". I don't think this is a scope problem as while() does not create a new scope in Python.

Please help!! It might be a really stupid mistake that I just can't find in my code!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appended four copies of **cell** to **col**.  Note that you didn't copy the values of **cell**: you copied the object reference!  Thus, you have four pointers to the original **cell** in **col**.  Every time you update **cell**, the update affects each reference ... they all point to the same object.

You seem to want a copy of **cell** instead.  Just change one line and ask for a new list:

```
col.append(list(cell))
```

Now you get the desired output:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[2, 1]
[3, 1]
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
```

Comment: Or you can use `cell[:]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now!